# Verb with ing is demonstrate state

Tags: questions

Suppose there is a tree and its some leaf has fallen on the land, so I would say as participle "the fallen leaf", but a person who is sitting on the chair why we say "sitting person" stead of "seated person"?

Please explain to me deeply.

Comment: The leaf has "fallen", the person is "sitting".

Comment: eques explains it well, but the short answer is that "seated person" is perfectly fine.  The person is seated.  They are a seated person.

Comment: @stangdon So, if we can say of the seated person "_They are a seated person,"_ can we then also say _"She are seated"_ or _"They is seated"_? (Could not resist.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Don't make me come over there with a printout of the "singular they" argument!  I guess there is the odd fact that singular they is semantically singular but grammatically plural...

Comment: @stangdon Hey, no prob. All verb forms is fine as long as the thought are clearly expressed!

Comment: A leaf has fallen but a person  is sitting. Fallen leaf versus sitting person. A seated person and a sitting person are not the same thing. It can get pretty tricky.  A broken record and a cooking pot [to cook, to be on the stove]

Comment: @Lambie the onus is on you to clarify what you mean. As a native speaker, I'd say they aren't that distinct. There are some slight differences in meaning or slight variations in expected usages

Answer (score 1):

We actually can say "seated person" but it's less common than "sitting person"

The reason why we can say "sitting person" for a person on a chair but we must say "fallen leaf" for a leaf which is on the ground is due to the difference in type of verb. **To fall** is an action verb, but **to sit** is stative in this usage. ** to sit down** is the corresponding action verb.

The action of the leave ("to fall") is completed and done. The leave is no longer in the process of that action; thus it is fallen (or has fallen). The person in the chair is in the state described by the verb, thus the person is sitting.

Comment: A seated person and a sitting person do not have the same meaning at all.

Comment: How so? We can say "seated person" where we would also say a "sitting person"; the two verbs are related, but not identical. Specifically, "sit" is a stative verb, but "seat" is a transitive action verb, which can thus be used reflexively/passively to indicate the resultant state.